# Add short signature + date to an existing paragraph of text and format the whole line

Tags: vba, outlook, format, selection

**Problem:**

I want to type a paragraph of text, add my short signature + date + time and format everything so another person would see I added this comment to the mail.

**Example:**

This is my personal comment on the topic // Signature Tom, 22.08.21, 14:00 (<- add the last part by VBA-Code and put this whole paragraph in red and italic by VBA)
Dear Sir or Madam 
...-> mail body 
Sincerely

**What I have**

So far it is two separate VBA sub routines I managed to create with trial and error from the web, but I would like it in one step (because I have to call them one after a time).

1st:

```
Option Explicit
Public Sub AddShortSignature()
    Dim xDoc As Object
    Dim xSel As Object
    
    On Error Resume Next
    Select Case TypeName(Application.ActiveWindow)
        Case "Explorer"
            Set xDoc = Application.ActiveExplorer.Selection(1).GetInspector.WordEditor
        Case "Inspector"
            Set xDoc = Application.ActiveInspector.WordEditor
    End Select
    
    Set xSel = xDoc.Application.Selection
    xSel.InsertBefore Format(Now, "DD/MM/YYYY hh/mm")
    xSel.InsertBefore Format(" // Tom., ")
    
    Set xDoc = Nothing
    Set xSel = Nothing
    
    SendKeys "{End}", True
    SendKeys "+{Home}", True

End Sub
```

and 2nd, format everything to my liking:

```
Sub formateverything()

    Dim objDoc As Object
    Dim objSel As Object
    
    Set objDoc = ActiveInspector.WordEditor
    Set objSel = objDoc.Windows(1).Selection

    objSel.Font.Name = "Arial"
    objSel.Font.Italic = True
    objSel.Font.Bold = False
    objSel.Font.Underline = False
    objSel.Font.Color = RGB(0, 0, 0)
    objSel.Font.Size = 14
    
End Sub
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

As I can see in your pictures, your comment and signature comes at the top of the mail (first paragraph), so this is what I came up with.

```
Public Sub OutlookMail_CommentAndSignature()
    Dim Ins As Outlook.Inspector
    Dim Doc As Object
    Dim mySignature As String
    Dim oPara As Object         ' paragraph
    Dim paraText As String      ' paragraph text
    Dim paraLength As Integer   ' paragraph length
    
    Set Ins = Application.ActiveInspector
    Set Doc = Ins.WordEditor
    
    ' Signature
    mySignature = " // Tom., " & Format(Now, "DD/MM/YYYY hh:mm") & vbCrLf

'    ' First paragraph: comment + signature
'    Set oPara = Doc.Paragraphs(1).Range
'    paraLength = Len(oPara.Text)
'    oPara.Text = Left(oPara.Text, paraLength - 1)   ' without vbCrLf
'    oPara.Text = oPara.Text & mySignature

'    ' format first paragraph
'    oPara.Font.Italic = wdToggle
'    oPara.Font.ColorIndex = wdRed
    
    ' Selected text
    Dim selRange As Object: Set selRange = Doc.Application.Selection.Range

    ' set text range to italic and red
    selRange.InsertAfter mySignature

    ' format first paragraph
    selRange.Font.Italic = wdToggle
    selRange.Font.ColorIndex = wdRed
End Sub
```

Comment: OK basically this is it! O_O amazing! it works as intented! one small and last question: (let's say I have to add a line break, what would I need to change to format all paragraphs before the cursor and add my signature after it? I changed Set oPara = Doc.Paragraphs(1).Range to (2) but then it selected the second Paragraph (and left the first untouched). anyways, thanks so much for your help.

Comment: Well I need more reputation to vote your answer up :D O-o

Comment: I just updated the code. This will  format the selected text and insert the signature after it. Although you can not vote, you can put a check if the answer was useful,

Answer (score 0):

This code sets the cursor to the end position of the message field, and the inserts a 'signature'. With this you set whatever position you want.

```
Public Sub OutlookMail_SetCursorAT()
    Dim Ins As Outlook.Inspector
    Dim Doc As Object
    Dim Range As Object
    Dim Pos As Long
    
    Set Ins = Application.ActiveInspector
    Set Doc = Ins.WordEditor
    
    ' Set the cursor to the end position of the message field
    If Not Doc Is Nothing Then
        Pos = Doc.Range.End - 1
        Set Range = Doc.Range(Pos, Pos)
        Range.Select
    End If
    
    ' Signature
    Dim mySignature As String
    mySignature = vbCrLf & Format(" // Tom., ")
    mySignature = mySignature & vbCrLf & Format(Now, "DD/MM/YYYY hh/mm")
    
    Range.InsertAfter mySignature
End Sub
```

Comment: your code is highly appreciated, but I have a few questions: 1. when I try to run it, office pops the error that "Dim Doc As Word.Document" <- Word.Document is not defiend (?), I change this to plain "Object" the complaint is gone (same goes for Word.Range). 2. how can I format the preexisting text in addition with that inserted Signature to lets say italic and red font color?

Comment: I updated the code so it does not need the reference to Microsoft Word library. In respect to your second question, what do you mean by 'preexisting text in addition with that inserted Signature''? Are you saying that you want to format the all document!? Can you post an example?

Comment: Me and other collegues organize mail for my boss. When a new email comes in it usually goes like this "Dear Sir or Madam... mailbody .... sincerely". Then I go into "Edit message mode", go to the very top (first line) of the email and add my statement so my boss can quickly catch up on the topic. workflow example: 1. I type some text about the mail topic in the first line 2. I add my signature at the end of the line like // Tom + date (works!) 3. I format my comment+sig so my boss can see it was not part of the original mail. last step would be nice to integrate in your vba code example

Comment: I do not understand! Create a dummy original mail (without any changes) and another with the changes you need, and post them as a picture.

Comment: OK first incoming mail looks like this: https://iili.io/RMzEfs.md.png" alt="RMzEfs.md.png and the second with my comment looks like this: https://iili.io/RMz80b.md.png now what I would like is to type my comment and then press one shortcut to automatically format my comment and add my short signature // Tom+date